# Why isn't Gcloud installing the "app-engine-go" component?

Tags: go, gcloud

I'm setting up Golang for App Engine on my Macbook Pro osX 0.11.6:
go version go1.8 darwin/amd64

I updated Cloud SDK to 148.0.0 with

sudo /usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud components update

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗  
╠═ Creating update staging area                             ═╣  
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣  
╠═ Uninstalling: BigQuery Command Line Tool                 ═╣  
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣  
╠═ Uninstalling: Cloud SDK Core Libraries                   ═╣  
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣  
╠═ Uninstalling: Cloud Storage Command Line Tool            ═╣  
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣     
╠═ Uninstalling: gcloud cli dependencies                    ═╣  
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣  
╠═ Installing: BigQuery Command Line Tool                   ═╣  
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣  
╠═ Installing: Cloud SDK Core Libraries                     ═╣  
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣  
╠═ Installing: Cloud Storage Command Line Tool              ═╣  
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣  
╠═ Installing: gcloud cli dependencies                      ═╣  
╠════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣  
╠═ Creating backup and activating new installation          ═╣   
╚════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Performing post processing steps...done.

$ dev_appserver.py app.yaml

```
This action requires the installation of components: [app-engine-go]  

Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 44, in <module>  
    main()  
  File "/usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/bin/dev_appserver.py", line 23, in main  
    command=__file__)  
  File "/usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/update_manager.py", line 189, in EnsureInstalledAndRestart  
    return manager._EnsureInstalledAndRestart(components, msg, command)  
  File "/usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/update_manager.py", line 1139, in _EnsureInstalledAndRestart  
    restart_args=restart_args):  
  File "/usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/update_manager.py", line 665, in Install  
    restart_args=restart_args)  
  File "/usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/updater/update_manager.py", line 742, in Update  
    config.EnsureSDKWriteAccess(self.__sdk_root)  
  File "/usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/config.py", line 195, in EnsureSDKWriteAccess  
    raise exceptions.RequiresAdminRightsError(sdk_root)  
googlecloudsdk.core.exceptions.RequiresAdminRightsError: You cannot perform this action because you do not have permission to modify the Google Cloud SDK installation directory [/usr/local/google-cloud-sdk].  

Re-run the command with sudo: sudo /usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud ...
```

What is the command I'm being told to run "sudo /usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud ..."  ?

Why isn't the "app-engine-go" component being installed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can see list of available components by running

```
gcloud components list
```

Many components are not installed by default, there are a few of them and some are rather large. If component is not installed you can install it via

```
gcloud components install app-engine-go
```

Since you have installed gcloud machine wide you would need to run last command with `sudo`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! You saved me a  lot of time.